# Closing jQuery Dialog box on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery dialog box that I use as a form, when I click the button it performs what it needs to, but does not close. How would I go about making it close on button click.

My current code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Change_Heat_Name').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('open');
    });
});
</script>
```

Button that opens the dialog:

```
Heat Name<input type="text" name="heat_name" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.heatname)" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" style ="width:100px"/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="Change_Heat_Name" value="Change_Heat_Name" name="action:Change_Heat_Name" type="button"> Change Heat Name</button>
```

Form inside the dialog box:

```
<div id="HeatNameDiv" title="Change Heat Name">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "chemDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "$(document).ready(function () { $('#ChangeHeatName').click(function () { $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');});});" }))
{
    <section>
        Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.heatname)" style ="width:100px"/>
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedHeat" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" name="ChangeHeatName" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
```

Comment: multiple `.ready` are not necessory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `close` allows you to do exactly what it name suggests: close the dialog:

```
$('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');
```

Also you seem to be calling this function inside the click event of some `#ChangeHeatName`. Make sure that you have canceled the default action if this is an anchor or a submit button to avoid the browser redirecting away from the page:

```
$('#ChangeHeatName').click(function () {
    $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, and this line should work fine. As the documentation of the jQuery UI dialog states, you should use the `.dialog('close')` method if you want to close the dialog. Don't hesitate to consult the documentation in case you are having some doubts: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

Comment: I guess the problem is that ChangeHeatName is not in the DOM when binding to the click event. Live would probably fix this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov In this case ChangeHeatName is the button in the dialog that pops up. It handles the submission of the form and I wanted the box to close when that happens. Does the fact that the button also submits have any effect?

Comment: @Danger_Fox, of course that it has an effect. It would depend on what you mean by *it submits*. If it submits the form normally without any AJAX then the webpage will get refreshed and the dialog would anyway get closed. If you are using AJAX on the other hand then that's a whole different story. In this case you could call the `.dialog('close')` method once your AJAX call succeeds. Unfortunately you haven't shown your AJAX code if you are using any, so it's pretty hard to help any further.

Comment: I am using AJAX. I'll update my question with the form so you can see. Sorry about that, I thought this would be a pure jQuery thing.

Comment: You could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` callback in the `AjaxOptions` and inside this callback close the dialog.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks, that makes sense. Question, how is that supposed to look? I've tried a few ways and looked it up, but I still can't get it to work. I'll update my form code in the question to show what it looks like.

Comment: `OnSuccess = "closeDialog"`. And then you define the `closeDialog` function: `function closeDialog() { $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close'); }`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Works perfectly! Thanks Darin

Answer (score 1):

Put all your code in one `$(document).ready()` and try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#Change_Heat_Name').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This will open the dialog
        $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#ChangeHeatName').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This will close the dialog
        $('#HeatNameDiv').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s7S6/)

Since the button in inside the dialog box, use the code below:

```
$('#ChangeHeatName').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ui-icon-closethick').click();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s7S6/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only problem is that the button I want to close it is in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for button in dialog and close the dialog on click

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, 
                    show: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 1000
                    },

                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
            $("#Closer").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            });
        });

 <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
   <button id="Closer">Close Dialog</button>
</div>
```

Open Dialog